# Look for duplicate records before adding a record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I clipped this from another post, since it is similar to what I need.  Instead of using me.ID, etc, I need to reference a field in another table, specifically [Formdate] in a table named Brief Sheet.

I tried many variations, such as table "Brief Sheet".Formdate  but no luck

What would be the proper syntax?

```
rst.FindFirst "[ID] <> " & Me.ID & _
 " AND [TitleText] = '" & Me.TitleText & _
 "' AND [UnitCode] = " & Me.UnitCode & _
 " AND [AcademicYear] = " & Me.AcademicYear & _
 " AND [Titleofchapterjournalarticle] = '" & Me.Titleofchapterjournalarticle &     "'"
```

Comment: Consider Dlookup https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937

Comment: Your field has to be in your recordset - what does your recordset query look like now? If it's in there you just use `[Formdate]` same as other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dlookup.  In the snippet you posted, the coder has already instantiated a recordset and is using recordset methods to find a record within it.  What you said you want to do is actually a little simpler.

Below is a test procedure to illustrate getting your date value from your table.

You didn't clarify what criteria you would use to select the proper FormDate from the table "Brief Sheet", so I included "ID=3", which will select the FormDate record, whose ID=3.  Adjust that as necessary.

Also, if your table name really is "Brief Sheet", and you have the ability to rename it, I highly recommend establishing some naming convention rules for your tables, first not having any spaces.  Even Brief_Sheet would make your life easier down the road.

```
    Public Sub Test1()

    'dimension a variable to hold the date value    
    Dim datFormDate As Date

    'fill the variable with the value you need to reference
    datFormDate = DLookup("FormDate", "Brief Sheet", "ID = 3")

    'Print the value to the "immediate" pane (just for testing)
    Debug.Print datFormDate

    'If you're running this code from within your form module, you can assign
  'the value in your variable to a field in your table as such:
me.DateFieldtxtbx = datFormDate

    End Sub
```

Comment: Note that dlookup returns null if a value is not found, so `Dim datFormDate As Date` will run into a problem.

Comment: Good point, Fionnuala.  One could either dimension the FormDate as a variant "Dim varFormDate as variant", or wrap the Dlookup statement in the Nz() function.